# how to output the specfic content reltaed to the title

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to make website which shows the judgements of various cases based on some conditions.
I pushing the data from database, where i upload the title of the judgment and the contents of the judgement. In the html file i have written this:

```
 {% for data in law_data %}
    {% if data.law_type == 'civil' and data.law_category == 'limitations' %}
        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLawtype(event,'title')">{{data.title}} &nbsp<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>  
        </div>
     
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here, after checking the conditions the titles are printed as buttons. The titles are pushed from the database. i want individual titles to show the judgements related to them. i wrote the following code for it:

```
 {% for data in law_data %}
    {% if data.title in data.judgments %}
        {{data.judgments|safe}}
    {% else %}
        <p> no data available</p>    
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def judge_civil(request):
    law_data= Laws.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    
    return render(request, 'judge_civil.html', {'law_data': law_data} )
```

**models.py**

```
class Laws(models.Model):
    date= models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=225, help_text="judgement title")
    judgments= RichTextField(blank=True, null= True)
    law_type= models.CharField(max_length=40, choices= type_of_law)
    law_category= models.CharField(max_length=60, choices= category)
```

However irrespective of whatever button i press all the judgements that are present in the database are printed.
I am unable to develop the logic for how to print the judgement that contains the title as part of it and print only the judgement that is related to title.

It will be very helpful if you can help develop the logic as I am beginner. Also please tell me if a different logic is used to make this kind of websites.

i am trying to this with if statements in the same page. If this is not the correct way to make this kind of website please suggest me how I can accomplish this task or exactly what kind of logic such websites use.

Comment: Is data.judgements a list? We need some more data. Could you post your views.py and models.py files as well. Can't reproduce this error without them

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui i have edited and provided the views and models please check. data.judgment is not a list it's a RichTextField

Comment: @Omar Siddiqui did you check ?